# OPENCV 2.4.9 Does resize change the pixel value?

Tags: opencv, resize

I am working on Classification problem with TIFF images. I am processing the entire images. But just at the last stage I am resizing the image to a smaller dimension for quick display. It is expected to get binary image, but resizing somehow introduces pixel of intermediate values because of which I get several gray spots in what is expected to be purely 0 or 255 pixel value ?

Answer (score 4):

When doing [re-sizing](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize), use the `INTER_NEAREST` interpolation type to avoid such cases:

> **`interpolation`** –
>   interpolation method:
>
> - **`INTER_NEAREST` - a nearest-neighbor interpolation**
> - `INTER_LINEAR` - a bilinear interpolation (used by default)
> - `INTER_AREA` - resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire’-free results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST method.
> - `INTER_CUBIC` - a bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood
> - `INTER_LANCZOS4` - a Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood